# How to disable change markers in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Where in the settings can i disable markers for added/modified lines?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure it in `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `General` | `Modified lines` / `Added lines`:

[image: modified background]

This changes the left gutter color, to modify the right stripe mark color go to the `Diff` color settings and change the color to be the same as the stripe gutter background:

[image: Diff]

Comment: I have these (added and modified lines) disabled

Comment: So, i have to explicitly set a color equal to border color? Also, disabling marks on the left still leaves the outline.

Comment: Can i just disable VCS tracking for single files, and only see file status in the project tree?

Comment: No, we have a related request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101042.